# Issue with EditorTemplates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

### **ASP.Net MVC 4.0 based Scenario:**

I need to render a set of Widgets[aka User Control with sets of custom fields] on a screen.
  The ViewModel for this Widget is something like this -

```
Public Class Widget
{
    public string Header {get;set;}

    //Note the data type here. It causes issues with rendering Widget itself.
    public object ActualContent {get;set;}

    public string Footer {get;set;}
}
```

At, run-time, say I want to render 2 widgets. Then all I need to do is create the instances as shown below :

```
Widget w1 = new Widget()
{ 
    Header ="PatientDetails", 

    ActualContent = new Patient ()
    {       
        FirstName = "ABC",
        LastName  = "XYZ" 
    }

    Footer = "PatientDetails 
};

Widget w2 = new Widget()
{ 
    Header ="Address-Header", 

    ActualContent = new Address ()
    {
        ZIPCode = "123456",
        Extn  = "1234" 
    }

    Footer = "Address-Footer" 
};
```

The cshtmls are :

```
Main Page i.e Widget.cshtml

@using Widgets.Models
@model List<Widget>
...
<div class="widget">
        <div class="header">
              @Model.Header
        </div>

        <div class="body" >
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ActualContent) 
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
              @Model.Footer
        </div>
</div>
...
Patient.cshtml in ~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates
@model Widgets.Models.Patient

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.LastName)
    </div>
```

Address.cshtml has a similar  implementation.

Note, the property ActualContent, is of type object. It can be assigned an instance of any UserControl [Patient,Address,etc] at runtime.
Also, each of the UserControls has a corresponding strongly typed cshtml view defined inside the EditorTemplates.

**Issue :** 
Now the issue is when I try to load the Widgets, I can see both the widgets getting rendered but only displaying the Header & Footer values.
The portion correponding to the ActualContent property, as shown above is not rendered at all, despite the fact that, while debigging, I can see that 
corresponding .cshtml for Patients & Address are getting accessed!

I feel there might be something that I may have missed out on.

It would be nice if someone can get this working for me. Thanks in advance.
Sandesh L.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access your Editor template like this,

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ActualContent, "_YourEditorTemplate")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did try specifying the template name earlier as shown below, but it didn't work out :
   Html.EditorFor(model => x, "Patient");  //EditoTemplate has Patient.cshtml

  I also tried explicit casting as well as shown here 
   
      Patient x = ((Patient)(Model.ActualContent));
  
    Html.EditorFor(model => x, (Model.ActualContent.GetType().Name));
        even this, 
    Html.EditorFor(model => x, x.GetType().Name);
  
  but still stuck at the same issue.

Thanks,
SandeshL

Comment: Also forgot to mention, even without specifiying the template name, it still DOES access my template.Only issues is withrendeing of the UI :(